Does "save time" go with "on something" and "Ving" to express that "you don't have to spend much time on something/Ving"?
I didn't find many sample sentences using "save time on something" or "save time V_ing", so I want to validate its use.
I'm guessing that "save time" and "waste time" go with the same structures, and the structures "waste time on something" and "waste time V_ing" are quite common, so is it correct and idiomatic to use "save time V_ing or on something", like in these sentences below?

I work from home instead of going to the office to save time on my daily commute


I work from home instead of going to the office to save time (on) commuting

If not, then what's the common way of using "save time" in the sense I mentioned above?

"saving time on (something)" means shaving time from it, not completely eliminating it.   "I can save time on commuting if I take the earlier train, which is an express with fewer stops".  But "save time (doing something)" can mean the same, but also to eliminate it.  "I can save time doing laundry if I join a nudist colony".

"save  time (on)"  are informal, colloquial expressions.

And there's also "save on time".  If we take this shortcut, we can save on time.  I.e. Reduce our expenditure of time, as it were; spend less time.  Get there  quicker.

Thank you for your clear explanation @TimR

The sentences are OK structurally, but they don't really make sense.
If you work from home, you don't have a commute, so you're not saving time, you're eliminating the commute altogether. A better example is:

Even though it's more expensive, I take the toll road to save time on my daily commute.

or "to save time on commuting" or "to save commute time."
